# Exponential increase in query time?

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-structures, relational-database

For the last couple of days I have been working on normalizing our 600GB database. 
I have broken out all redundant data into 4 separate tables plus a main entry table.

All is well so far, but the last step, joining the new tables with the old data records and inserting the new normalized data records into the database.For this I'm using `"INSERT INTO SELECT"`. But not to the problem. If i run this query on the first 100 id's It takes 10sec but if I run it on the first 300 rows it takes several minutes. What can I do to fix this?

```
SELECT * FROM oldDB.`unNormalized` 
INNER JOIN `new_normalized_db`.`keyword` k ON `unNormalized_tabel`.`keyword` = k.`keyword`
INNER JOIN `new_normalized_db`.`project` p ON `unNormalized_tabel`.`awrProject` = p.`project`
INNER JOIN `new_normalized_db`.`searchEngine` s ON `unNormalized_tabel`.`searchEngine` = s.`searchEngine`
INNER JOIN `new_normalized_db`.`urlHash` u ON MD5(`unNormalized_tabel`.`url`) = u.`hash`
WHERE oldDB.`unNormalized_tabel`.`id` < 100
GROUP BY k.`id`, p.`id`, s.`id`,u.`id`
```

As of right now the old entrys only have a primery key index, should I add a full text index to all the old data columns? Am thinking this could take months on a 600gb un-normalized database? And what about space how much extra space does 4 new indexes take up?

```
 id  select_type  table              type    possible_keys                                                    key           key_len  ref                                 rows  Extra                                         
------  -----------  -----------------  ------  ---------------------------------------------------------------  ------------  -------  --------------------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------
     1  SIMPLE       p                  index   (NULL)                                                           projectName   42       (NULL)                               427  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort  
     1  SIMPLE       unormalized_tabel  range   PRIMARY,keyword_url_insDate,keyword,searchEngine,url,awrProject  PRIMARY       4        (NULL)                               358  Using where; Using join buffer                
     1  SIMPLE       u                  ref     url                                                              url           767      oldDB.unormalized_tabel.url       1                                                
     1  SIMPLE       k                  index   (NULL)                                                           keyword       42       (NULL)                            107340  Using where; Using index; Using join buffer   
     1  SIMPLE       s                  index   (NULL)                                                           searchEngine  42       (NULL)                              1155  Using where; Using index; Using join buffer
```

Comment: I suppose there is no way to get rid of the MD5 function call in the last JOIN condition?

Comment: Two general rules: 1) columns used in joins should be indexed (full text not necessarily required, non-clustered is ok) for optimal performance and 2) functions typically negate the ability to use indexes on joins, so the MD5 function could be causing significant problems.  You can check how your query is working using `EXPLAIN` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: I  could remove the MD5 hash and just match on the pure urls' but in small test cases (10 row) the MD5 matching  actually  seam to be faster :/

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your query by adding indexes.

The first join of `k` can be faster if there is an index on `keyword` and also an index on `unNormalized_tabel.keyword` the same for project `p` with `awrProject` and `p.project` and `s.searchEngine` and `unNormalized_tabel.searchEngine`

But the last join will be slow anyway, because a hash must be calculated on query time, which is very slow on much data. What you can do is hash the `url` before inserting in the `unNormalized_tabel`, and then add an index on the hash_field.